# Can OUT parameter values still be written even if a PL/SQL procedure raises an error?

Tags: oracle, error-handling, plsql

I have a PL/SQL procedure with an `OUT` parameter. How can I force the `OUT` parameter values to be written, even if an error is raised? Is there another mechanism for returning values when an error is raised?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on @APC's answer, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3372) says:

*If you exit a subprogram successfully, PL/SQL assigns values to OUT parameters. However, if you exit with an unhandled exception, PL/SQL does not assign values to OUT parameters (unless they are NOCOPY parameters).*

Here are some examples that might help illustrate:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> REM Example 1 -- OUT parameter value is unchanged if an exception was raised after value was assigned
SQL> declare
  2      x number := 1;
  3      procedure p(x out number)
  4      as
  5      begin
  6          x := 2;
  7          raise program_error;
  8      end p;
  9  begin
 10      p(x);
 11  exception
 12      when program_error then
 13          dbms_output.put_line
 14          (
 15              case
 16                  when x is null then 'null'
 17                  else to_char(x)
 18              end
 19          );
 20  end;
 21  /
1                                                                               

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> REM Example 2 -- OUT parameter value is unchanged if value was set in exception handler and exception was then re-raised
SQL> declare
  2      x number := 1;
  3      procedure p(x out number)
  4      as
  5      begin
  6          x := 2;
  7          raise program_error;
  8      exception
  9          when program_error then
 10              x := 3;
 11              raise;
 12      end p;
 13  begin
 14      p(x);
 15  exception
 16      when program_error then
 17          dbms_output.put_line
 18          (
 19              case
 20                  when x is null then 'null'
 21                  else to_char(x)
 22              end
 23          );
 24  end;
 25  /
1                                                                               

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> REM Example 3 -- OUT parameter value is changed if value was set in exception handler and exception was not re-raised
SQL> declare
  2      x number := 1;
  3      procedure p(x out number)
  4      as
  5      begin
  6          x := 2;
  7          raise program_error;
  8      exception
  9          when program_error then
 10              x := 3;
 11      end p;
 12  begin
 13      p(x);
 14      dbms_output.put_line
 15      (
 16          case
 17              when x is null then 'null'
 18              else to_char(x)
 19          end
 20      );
 21  end;
 22  /
3                                                                               

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> REM Example 4 -- OUT NOCOPY parameter value is changed if an exception was raised
SQL> declare
  2      x number := 1;
  3      procedure p(x out nocopy number)
  4      as
  5      begin
  6          x := 2;
  7          raise program_error;
  8      end p;
  9  begin
 10      p(x);
 11  exception
 12      when program_error then
 13          dbms_output.put_line
 14          (
 15              case
 16                  when x is null then 'null'
 17                  else to_char(x)
 18              end
 19          );
 20  end;
 21  /
2                                                                               

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I think there is a missunderstanging here. the value is null in some examples because is not initiated. if we declare `    x number:=7;` then the value will remain 7 in examples 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Florin Ghita.  I've modified the examples to initialize the value of x in an attempt to make it clearer when its value is changed or not.

Answer (score 4):

When a PL/SQL program raises an exception Oracle does not assign values to OUT parameters.  If This is a safety feature, because it gives us all the parameters in a known and consistent state

However, sometimes that is not what we want.  For instance, we might want to use an OUT parameter to pass an error message or other helpful information to the calling program.  We can set OUT parameters in the EXCEPTIONS section of the program.   Those values are passed out (unless the handler itself raises an exception).

Comment: Can you give a reference for that(setting OUT params to null)?

Comment: Just a slight clarification. This will not work if the caught exception is re-raised.

Comment: I think the value will **not be changed** if the procedure exits with exception. Null happens only when the value was null before running the PL/SQL program.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - I get the distinction you're making and I think you're right (don't have a DB to hand to check).  However, I would always expect a variable used as an OUT parameter to be null.  In that if the variable contains a meaningful value it should either only be used as an IN OUT parameter or it shouldn't be used at all.